# Parameters in Javascript and Java

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I'm currently sending an ajax request to a servlet and losing some information along the way. The parameter I am concerned about(losing data from) is the "comment" parameter. Below you can see my last 4 lines of ajax.

```
var params = "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&comment=" + comment + "&player_id=" + player_id;    
xmlhttp.open("POST", 'comment', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

When I alert my params before the send and after the declaration they look like this:

```
name=Chris&email=email@gmail.com&comment=Hey, check this song out on groovershark http://grooveshark.com/#!/s/Here+feat+Soulive/2YDJIw?src=5&player_id=4
```

However in my servlet if I do a print line for the comment parameter right after getting it I get this output:

```
Hey, check this song out on groovershark http://grooveshark.com/#!/s/Here feat Soulive/2YDJIw?src=5
```

The problem is the `"+"` marks disappear somewhere along the request from ajax to the container and I have no idea why. I have narrowed it down to this problem area finally b/c I actually did not notice this until all the way in the database connection with the help of another stack overflow member. So if anyone could let me know what I can do to get my `"+"` characters back I would really really appreciate! Thank you so much!

Comment: `+` are being translated to spaces, you need to encode the url part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode your params prior to send them, like this:

```
encodeURIComponent(params);
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm confused as to how I encode the parameters. I tried encodeURIComponent(params); but that did not change anything. on the server side there are still spaces not %2B. I'm sorry but what should I do from here exactly?

Comment: thank you so much. if you have time could i talk with u for two minutes I have a quick question about this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18153/js-help

Comment: @Nelson after you encode param. you need to decode in servlet using URLDecode http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Answer (score 0):

You should percent encode the params part of the URI:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters

In this way + becomes %2B and can be interpreted correctly on the server side.

Check out the encodeURIComponent() function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp